# Get text from div using Selenium in a dynamically named class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div class="jss14 jss41">
 <div class="rn-obd0qt rn-1efd50x rn-14skgim rn-rull8r rn-mm0ijv rn-13yce4e rn-fnigne rn-ndvcnb rn-gxnn5r rn-deolkf rn-6koalj rn-1qe8dj5 rn-1mlwlqe rn-eqz5dr rn-1h0z5md rn-1mnahxq rn-61z16t rn-p1pxzi rn-11wrixw rn-ifefl9 rn-bcqeeo rn-wk8lta rn-9aemit rn-1mdbw0j rn-gy4na3 rn-bnwqim rn-1lgpqti">
   <div color="#777" dir="auto" class="rn-13yce4e rn-fnigne rn-ndvcnb rn-gxnn5r rn-deolkf rn-1471scf rn-1b43r93 rn-o11vmf rn-ebii48 rn-t9a87b rn-1mnahxq rn-61z16t rn-p1pxzi rn-11wrixw rn-wk8lta rn-9aemit rn-1mdbw0j rn-gy4na3 rn-bauka4 rn-q42fyq rn-qvutc0" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119); font-family: Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">$6.49</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am looking to extract the $6.49 value.

I have only found posts that have shown how to do this when the class name is static, such as:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_2v66')

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

How to approach this when the class name is dynamically created on click?

Edit:

More outerHTML as requested:
[image]s://i.stack.imgur.com/m65D8.png

Comment: if className is dynamic then try with other locators like xpath..cssSelector.. provide bit more html code to try it out

Comment: Update the question with a bit of outerHTML

Comment: Done.  Added more of the outer HTML, which is more dynamically named classes.

Comment: Can you provide the actual url?

Comment: Do you any label for this field? if there is please add that dom as well. I mean preceding sibling of <div class="jss14 jss41">?

Comment: @JohnS The text **$6.49** will be always associated with a parameter mostly a `<span>` or a `<label>` tag/node and that reference tag/node would be clue to retrieve the text. So you needto provide a bit more of the outerHTML.

Comment: Does this help?  https://imgur.com/iwsuap5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we don't find any unique attribute matching, then we can go with dom parent/sibiling structure or displayed text value or combining to get the unique non changing locator.

For example,

- Here div has two immediate parent. we can take this a criteria.  so div>div>div css locator will reduced result.
- Then I guess dir="auto" is not changing, we can include that as well. So the css will be  div>div>div[dir='auto']
- If value is displayed, definitely it may have label preceding it.

**Amount :** $6.49

For e.g.
If you have label before the div.

```
    <label> Amount</label>
    <div class="jss14 jss41">
      <div class="rn-obd0qt rn-1efd50x rn-14skgim rn-rull8r rn-mm0ijv rn-13yce4e rn-fnigne rn-ndvcnb rn-gxnn5r rn-deolkf rn-6koalj rn-1qe8dj5 rn-1mlwlqe rn-eqz5dr rn-1h0z5md rn-1mnahxq rn-61z16t rn-p1pxzi rn-11wrixw rn-ifefl9 rn-bcqeeo rn-wk8lta rn-9aemit rn-1mdbw0j rn-gy4na3 rn-bnwqim rn-1lgpqti">
       <div color="#777" dir="auto" class="rn-13yce4e rn-fnigne rn-ndvcnb rn-gxnn5r rn-deolkf rn-1471scf rn-1b43r93 rn-o11vmf rn-ebii48 rn-t9a87b rn-1mnahxq rn-61z16t rn-p1pxzi rn-11wrixw rn-wk8lta rn-9aemit rn-1mdbw0j rn-gy4na3 rn-bauka4 rn-q42fyq rn-qvutc0" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119); font-family: Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">$6.49</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Then you can use that to find this element like,

```
//label[text() == 'Amount']/following-sibling::div/div/div
```

Please find the nearest or parent non changing value and traverse to the required element.